# Plotting density lines of distributions in log-log scale (base 10) with R

Tags: r, plot, distribution

I know about the parameter `log="xy"`, but I don't know whether you can control the base of the logarithmic scale (my guess is that 10 may be the default (?)), and I'm not getting lucky on the specific issue below...

How can I reproduce the following plot ([from this source](http://www.uvm.edu/pdodds/teaching/courses/2013-01UVM-300/docs/2013-01UVM-300lognormals-flat.pdf)) with R. In particular, I am having problems with the log base 10 x and y axes.

[image]

Leaving aside the power law red line, I was playing with

```
x = rlnorm(1e4,0,10)
h = hist(x, prob=T, plot=F)
plot(h$count, log="xy", type="l", lend=2)
```

without success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the pdf of the lognormal in base10

[image]

[Generalising it to other log-bases is straightforward.]

We can then plot the pdf on a log10-log10 scale.

## (gg)plotting

```
# lognormal base log10 pdf, w is in log10
lognorm_base10 <- function(w, mu, sigma) {
    log10(exp(1)) / (sqrt(2*pi*sigma^2) * 10^w) * exp(- (w - mu)^2 / (2 * sigma^2));
}

# Generate data for mu = 0, sigma = 10 
x <- seq(0, 10, length.out = 100);
y <- lognorm_base10(x, 0, 10);

# Plot
require(ggplot2);
gg <- ggplot(data.frame(x = x, y = y), aes(x, y));
gg <- gg + geom_line() + scale_y_log10();
gg <- gg + labs(x = "log10(x)", y = "log10(p)")
```

[image]

## Plotting without ggplot

```
plot(x, log10(y), type = "l")
```

[image]

Comment: @Mako212 Thanks, I always choose to use `;`. My heritage from coding in C, and in my opinion it's good practise. There are a lot of discussions on SO and elsewhere on the pros and cons. Matter of choice and what you're used to I guess.

Comment: Fair enough, just thought I'd mention since I rarely see the semi-colon outside of an inline set of statements.

Comment: Without `ggplot()` it would simply be `plot(x,log10(y), type="l")`.Thank you!

Comment: @Toni Cheers, I've added the base R plotting option as well. You can change the scales in `ggplot` using `coord_cartesian(ylim = c(10^(-12), 10^(-1)))`.

Comment: No worries @Mako212. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: I just wanted to make you aware of [this "sister" post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47048035/4089351) in case you feel like tackling it. I can place a bounty on it (even after an answer is provided).