# Plotting area of overlap lognormal and power law distributions

Tags: r, plot, distribution

From [this source](http://www.uvm.edu/pdodds/teaching/courses/2013-01UVM-300/docs/2013-01UVM-300lognormals-flat.pdf), I am trying to reproduce the following plot:

[image]

Earlier, I posted a question regarding the log10-log10 plot of the lognormal distribution, and got an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47045421/4089351):

```
# lognormal base log10 pdf, w is in log10
lognorm_base10 <- function(w, mu, sigma) {
    log10(exp(1)) / (sqrt(2*pi*sigma^2) * 10^w) * exp(- (w - mu)^2 / (2 * sigma^2))
}

# Generate data for mu = 0, sigma = 10 
x = seq(0, 10, length.out = 101)
y = lognorm_base10(x[2:101], 0, 10)
```

[image]

I thought overlapping the power law was going to be easy with `p(x) = c * x^-gamma`, where `c = 0.03` and `gamma = 1`.

However, this is not the case, getting something as disparate as

```
# Generating the power law density curve:
alpha <- -1
C     <- 0.03
z     <- log10(C) + alpha * log10(x[2:101])

plot(x[2:101], log10(y), type = "l")
lines(x[2:101], z, type= 'l', col=2)
```

[image]

I can get a line as log(p(x)) = log C -alpha * log(x):

[image]

but not if I intend to keep the same x axis, ranging from 0 to 10 to plot both densities in one single plot.

Multiple logarithmic combinations haven't solved the issue. What am I missing?

Comment: The power law distribution is usually only defined for exponents > 1; you won't be able to normalise the pdf otherwise, unless you truncate the distribution for large x. So I'm not sure how the power law distribution was parametrised in your case, and what the parameters `gamma` and `c` are. Can you edit your question and include the pdf `f(x | gamma, c)`?

Comment: @MauritsEvers Right, typically exponents from 2 - 4? I had included the pdf, although without LaTeX it's difficult to miss it. It would be `p(x) = c * x^-gamma`, where`c = 0.03` and `gamma = 1`. I don't have more than the picture in the OP, so it's just a guess.

Comment: The pdf is usually defined for *any* exponent > 1; not sure why you think between 2 and 4. But either way, `gamma = 1` makes no sense given the form of the pdf. Unless you truncate in some way (e.g. `p(x) = c * x^gamma * exp(-lambda *x)`, the pdf cannot be normalised.

Comment: @MauritsEvers Yes, you're right - in all honesty, I was so fixated on the caption on the picture in the OP, that when you mentioned it the first time around, it didn't sink in. By the way, I tracked down the source of the 2 - 4 - in fact in [this article by M. E. J. Newman](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~mejn/courses/2006/cmplxsys899/powerlaws.pdf), page 4, it says "most power-law distributions occurring in nature 2 \leq \alpha \leq 3". So I guess from 2 to 3 (not 4).

Comment: Nice article; by the way, page 8 also discusses why power law cdf's are only defined for exponents > 1. So I assume `gamma` is not the exponent. Unless your course material gives an explicit form of the pdf, this is a bit of guessing game to find the right pdf that reproduces the plot...

Comment: @MauritsEvers I totally see your point. This is not a course I'm taking, but something I came across online, the log-log plot of a log-normal is an inverted parabolic shape, and I wanted to show to myself that at some segment of the sloping descent a linear log-log plot of a power law could be nearly indistinguishable.

Comment: In a log-log plot the lognormal distribution does *not* have a parabolic shape! You show that the shape is a straight line in the first part of your question set. As to the similarity between the lognormal and power law distributions: That's an interesting and well-studied question, but would go beyond the scope of SO; perhaps you're better off discussing this on [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @MauritsEvers  Check [these 30 - 60' of this Stanford video](https://youtu.be/ymgwuqJw_w0?t=29m49s). What am I missing? I tried getting some quadratic form here: `set.seed(1); x = rlnorm(1e5); x = x[x < 10]; plot(density(x), log="xy", type="l", xlim=c(.03, 8), col = 4, lwd = 2, main="Log-normal distribution")` at the bottom of [my notes online](http://rinterested.github.io/statistics/power_law.html).

Comment: Sorry but I don't have time to watch 30 minutes of a Youtube video. The log-likelihood of the lognormal is nearly linear for large `sigma` parameters. That's what you confirmed in the first part of your question (where `sigma = 10`). *Generally*, you have a quadratic term in the log-likelihood that gives you the shape you see in your notes. So there's no inconsistency. You're introducing more and more different concepts, which goes a bit far for a single post here on SO: log base transformations, plotting cdf's in R, similarity between power law and lognormal cdfs...

Comment: @MauritsEvers Thank you. About the video, I had clipped it right at the time when the teacher makes the assertion (30 seconds more or less from the linked time). But it seems like there is no inconsistency from the rest of your comment.

Comment: No worries. The question about the extent to which the power law and lognormal distributions agree is an interesting one, and has been well researched. Some features can already be seen by looking at the log-likelihood functions of both distributions. For a deeper insight into the underlying processes and its characteristics (e.g. scale invariance etc.) that may give rise to those distributions you'd have to study a stats textbook. Good luck with your research!

Comment: @MauritsEvers maybe power is not 1 but shall be derived from `c` as on slide 15? `\gamma = 1 + 1/(1-c)` ? For c=0.03 it gives power a bit over 2, which is reasonable